# Regex to match "<some_word_which_should_not_contain_%%>%%<some_word_which_should_not_contain_%%>"

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a string like `abc%%def`. The only thing I want to add to this rule is that the first part before `%%` (`abc` here) and the second part after `%%` (`def` here) should not be a string that contains `%%`.

That is, doing something like `(.+)%%(.+)`, it also matches `abc%%def%%ghi`, and the first part is matched to `abc%%def`, which is something I do not want to allow.

What is the correct regex for this?

Comment: Is `a%bc%%de%f%%ghi` a valid match?

Comment: @anubhava `a%bc%%de%f%%ghi` is a valid match. It matches `a%bc%%de%f` to the first group and `ghi` to the second group.

Comment: What is your regex platform?

Comment: @Thefourthbird That also avoids matching `abc%%def%ghi`, i.e. even single `%`. I want to allow single-ones in a group, just not a double `%%`

Comment: @user2684198 I see it, I will remove the comment.

Comment: @anubhava Nope, the `abc%%def%%ghi` also matches (`abc%%def` is greedily matched to the first group.

Comment: Sorry not getting now. Can you update question and show few input strings with expected matches. e.g. what is expected output for `abc%%def%%ghi` or `a%bc%%de%f%%ghi` ?

Comment: add more sample and explanation, your question is not clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use following regex:

`^((?:(?<!%)%(?!%)|[^%])+)%%((?:(?<!%)%(?!%)|[^%])+)$`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pQcV1v/1/)

**Details:**

`^`: start of the line

`((?:(?<!%)%(?!%)|[^%])+)`: non matching group that says character should not be `%` or if it's `%`, it should not have any other `%` before of after it. it will go for is greedy.

`%%`: 2 character that should be as separator

`((?:(?<!%)%(?!%)|[^%])+)` same said pattern for after separator characters

`$`: end of line